# Newly Created & Loaded StatefulKnowledgeSession - JBPM 5

Tags: drools, jbpm

**strong text**What could be the problem if the task-completed event is not getting dispatched to the StatefulKnowledgeSession ?

For a new process-instance, I do

- create a new session

  register human-task local GenericHTWorkItemHandler

  register custom event listeners

  call `startProcess(processDefinitionId,parameters);`

It starts a new instance, creates the first human-task via the registered human-task-handler.

When I want to complete the human-task, I do

- restore the KnowledgeSession with
  `JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(lastSessionId,kBase,null,
  env);`

  again register human-task local GenericHTWorkItemHandler

  again register custom event listeners

Then call taskService.completeTask, BUT the task-completed is not dispatched to the KnowledgeSession. And the process-flow is not happening

Should I not register the event listeners again ?
Should I not register the work-item-handlers again ?

**Update 1**
Exception trace:

```
07:52:09,618 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/workflow-console].[rsservlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8280-15) Servlet.service() for servlet rsservlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1158) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.drools.container.spring.beans.persistence.DroolsSpringJpaManager.getApplicationScopedPersistenceContext(DroolsSpringJpaManager.java:89) [drools-spring-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
        at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:350) [drools-persistence-jpa-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
        at org.drools.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.getEnvironment(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:478) [drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar:5.5.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler.handleCompletedTask(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:260) [jbpm-human-task-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler$TaskCompletedHandler.execute(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:234) [jbpm-human-task-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService$SimpleEventTransport.trigger(LocalTaskService.java:329) [jbpm-human-task-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
```

When reloading a session I am registering new HumanTaskWorkItemhandlers.It keeps on registering event handlers with the TaskService.

When I connect the workItemHandlers, they register eventHandlers with the taskService.
When will this eventHandlers get de-registered from the taskService ?

Comment: Which version of jBPM is this?

Comment: Environment:JBPM 5.4.0.Final, Drools 5.5.0.Final, Jboss 7.1.0.Final

Comment: Hmm.. sorry to ask for more information: do you have a little bit of code that you could show? It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Are you making sure to use the correct (new, reloaded) ksession when you re-register the handler and listeners?

Comment: I debugged through the code, task-completed-event was dispatched to more than 1 session.It must be a problem with my ksession management.I think I must create the GenericHTWorkItemHandler with `owningKSessionOnly=true`

Comment: @Marco , I have added the error trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a task service, it will by default dispatch events to all listeners.  So that means multiple ksessions can receive the event (but a task completion event should only be processed by one ksession).  As you mentioned, using owningKSessionOnly can be used to make sure only one ksession will react to the completion event.

You can deregister the listeners of the handler by calling dispose on the handler.